# Gradle tests read from XML files

Tags: java, junit, gradle

My junit4 test cases read from XML files located under my main test source folder under a directory "src/myTest/java/data".

When I execute my tests I get file not found exception because it does not know about this data folder. What is the best way to include these XML files so when I execute my tests, gradle is able to pick up on the location of these data files.

thanks

**Update**

I moved the data files to the resource directory and I am now able to specify my resource dir in my test execution.

```
task myTests(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.myTests.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.myTests.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.myTests.resources
}
```

But when I compile my tests it doesn't seem to output the resources into 'build/resources/myTests' and I have a feeling thats why I need to specify the resources folder in the classpath to include 'sourceSets.myTests.resources' otherwise it would have already picked up on it from the build path.

```
sourceSets {
    myTests {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
        }
        resources {
            include "*.xml"
            output.resourcesDir 'build/resources/myTests'
        }
    }
}

task myTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.myTests.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.myTests.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.myTests.resources
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can try this

```xml
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.resourcesDir = ['src/test/resources', 'src/smokeTest/java/data']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle by default is expecting test resources at `src/test/resources/`.  If you've got a file like `src/test/resources/data/pluto.xml`

```
ClassLoader classLoader = CommonResourceUtil.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream( "data/pluto.xml" );
```

There is probably an easier way to getResourceAsStream.  The point is `src/test/resources/` is on the classpath for the tests so you use relative paths from there.

I'm sure there is a longer way to configure the gradle test task to put your own directory on the classpath, but that will have everyone later wondering why its there and not just at the default location.  I recommend that you move your test files into `src/test/resources/` and work it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

By default, gradle assumes that you have organized your project using the [Apache Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). This layout includes a folder `src/test/resources`, whose contents are [put on the classpath](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#N103DE) when you execute your tests.

Thus, the easiest way to include these xml-files in your tests would be to follow that layout and place them in `src/test/resources`. Depending on how you configured your build, `src/smokeTest/resources` may also work.

You can then access the resources as described in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) tutorial. Basically, the easiest way to access such a file would be as follows (copied from the tutorial):

```
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
  name = resolveName(name);
  ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
  if (cl==null) {
    return ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(name); // A system class.
  }
  return cl.getResourceAsStream(name);
}

public java.net.URL getResource(String name) {
  name = resolveName(name);
  ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
  if (cl==null) {
    return ClassLoader.getSystemResource(name);  // A system class.
  }
  return cl.getResource(name);
}
```